# React Hooks - render component conditionally based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a basic `react` functional component with hooks.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Header from 'test-header';
import Dashboard from 'test-dashboard';
import { api } from '../api';

function storeUser(user) {
  if (user) {
    localStorage.user = JSON.stringify(user);
  } else {
    delete localStorage.user;
  }
}

async function login() {
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  try {
    const user = await api({
      endpoint: 'identity/login',
      method: 'POST',
      json: {
        email: 'test@abc.com',
        password: '12345'
      }
    });
    setUser(user);
    storeUser(user);
  } catch (err) {
    setError(err);
  }
}

function Container() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" onClick={login}></input>
      {/* if user sets in state then render <Dashboard /> else render error message  */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Container;
```

Here, `test-header` component published as `npm` package works fine. When I click the `Login` button, I am getting this error:

> react-dom.development.js?61bb:16178 Uncaught (in promise) Error:
>   Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
>   function component.

**How do I check whether `user` has been set in state or not and based on that render `Dashboard` component with `react-hooks`?**

Comment: [Rules of hooks: Only call Hooks from React function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not calling hooks from functional component. I hope the following addresses your concern.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Header from 'test-header';
import Dashboard from 'test-dashboard';
import {api} from '../api';

const Container = props => {
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  function storeUser(user) {
    if (user) {
      localStorage.user = JSON.stringify(user);
    } else {
      delete localStorage.user;
    }
  }
  async function login() {
    try {
      const user = await api({
        endpoint: 'identity/login',
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
          email: 'test@abc.com',
          password: '12345',
        },
      });
    // call setUser only if credentials are correct
      if (validUser) {
        setUser(user);
        storeUser(user);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" onClick={login}></input>
      {user.length > 0 ? <Dashboard /> : error.length > 0 ? <Error /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the state out of `login`. Move the hook into another hook. Call that hook in a functional component:

```
  function useUser() {
    const [error, setError] = useState([]);
    const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

    async function login() {
      try {
        const user = await api({   endpoint: 'identity/login', method: 'POST', json: { email: 'test@abc.com',  password: '12345'  }   });
        setUser(user);
        storeUser(user);
      } catch (err) { setError(err);  }
   }
   return { user, error, login };
 }


 function Container() {
   const { user, error, login } = useUser();
   //...
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer with clean code. I got the point of having state at top level of a component. Accepted the previous answer because it was posted first and addressed the same issue.